# Strong Name Validation Failed while running C# app in custom AppDomain from unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, appdomain, strongname

I have a program that make use of unmanaged C++ code, and I want to write Unit Tests (well, more like system tests) for it.

I want to run the entire program from the Unit Test in a different AppDomain, so I'll be able to more easily inject tester code.

Problem is, when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
The C++ module failed to load while attempting to initialize the default appdomain
(source: my own code)

Inner Exception:

Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
(source: msvcm90)
```

I use the MSTest as testing environment.

I already tried altering some `app.config` files, but maybe the wrong ones. I also tried using the `AppDomainSetup` object, but I don't know what to configure there to prevent it from performing strong name check.

I'm launching the app from the unit test using `AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly`.

**Edit**

The latest thing I've tried is to use `appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` to load a proxy class I made, that also implements `MarshalByRefObject`. The proxy class loads fine, but in it I try to call the function which starts the initialization and runs the actual code I want to test, and the above error still occur.

I've tried using `fuslogvw.exe` but I don't get anything from it. I guess it is because what fails is loading of an unmanaged DLL.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot this.  Post the trace you get when you need more help.

Comment: Tried that. Fuslogvw gives me nothing, unfortunately. It fails loading a native code, so fuslogvw won't show it.

Comment: That's unlikely, try starting Fuslogvw from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: I did, I'm not new to the fusion log.